# Showing string depending on the value of an array that have some position

Tags: php, arrays

In my eCommerce I have some ways to shop and I want to showing some string depended of every way by which user shops on my site.

I have an array to show for all the ways that the user shops on my site, but these ways come from a separate string with a `,` separated.

array looks like

```
$array = [
       array(
       'userShop' => '1,0,0',
       'userId' => 245
       ),

       array(
       'userShop' => '1,1,1',
       'userId' => 12 
       ),

       array(
       'userShop' => '0,1,0',
       'userId' => 25 
       )
];
```

in array index `userShop` - first INT meaning `POS` deposit and second INT meaning `card deposit` and third INT meaning `cash deposit`. `0` meaning don`t going this way and 1 meaning doing shop by this way

and I want to get output like this:

```
<p>245</p>
<p>POS</p>
<hr>

<p>12</p>
<p>POS, Cart, Cash</p>
<hr>

<p>25</p>
<p>Cart</p>
<hr>
```

I can do this with `if` and`elseif` for all methods and ways, but it's really boring.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this `foreach` loop:

```
$names = ['POS', 'Card', 'Cash'];

foreach($array as $rec){

    $nums = explode(',',$rec['userShop']);      // explode
    $rnames = [];                               
    foreach ($nums as $ind=>$val){              // check each 1 or 0
        if ($val) $rnames[] = $names[$ind];     // fill the names
    } 

    // print result
    echo '<p>'.$rec['userId'].'</p>'.PHP_EOL. 
         '<p>'.join(', ',$rnames).'</p>'.PHP_EOL.
         '<hr>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Outputs:

```
<p>245</p>
<p>POS</p>
<hr>
<p>12</p>
<p>POS, Card, Cash</p>
<hr>
<p>25</p>
<p>Card</p>
<hr>
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/hXq11)**